# Mongo SSL certificate error

Tags: mongodb, ssl, https

This is what I did exactly for establishing SSL connection.

1 Use openssl to generate a client and a server key (c.pem, s.pem)

2 Use openssl to generate a client key request and server key request

3 Get CA to sign both req and get the certs:  c.cer  , s.cer

4 concatenate c.pem and c.cer  and get client.pem,  similarly, get server.pem

Now start the server:

`mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile server.pem -sslCAFile caroot.cer`

start the client:

`mongo --ssl --sslCAFile caroot.cer --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem`

And now I am getting the error:

`E NETWORK  SSL peer certificate validation failed:certificate not trusted`

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work?